# WordPress: Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Tags: php, wordpress, timezone

Hi for some reason i cant access my website i get this error code:

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531

> Fatal error: mysqli_real_connect(): Timezone database is corrupt -
>   this should *never* happen! in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on
>   line 1531

I have gone to look at that line of code:

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
                mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
            } else {
                @mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
        }

        if ( $this->dbh->connect_errno ) {
            $this->dbh = null;

            /*
             * It's possible ext/mysqli is misconfigured. Fall back to ext/mysql if:
             *  - We haven't previously connected, and
             *  - WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL isn't set to false, and
             *  - ext/mysql is loaded.
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill the `date.timezone` value in your php.ini
or with the `date_default_timezone_set` function at the start of your script :

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Comment: i'm now getting this: Warning: ini_set(): Invalid date.timezone value 'UTC', we selected the timezone 'UTC' for now. in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 3

Fatal error: ini_set(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 3

Comment: Just updated my answer

Comment: Now I'm getting this instead:

Comment: Warning: date_default_timezone_set(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2

Comment: Fatal error: date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2

Comment: Did you put your statement before the query ?

Comment: Yes i did, still not working